# click handler to an individual isolated Sprite

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

is there a way to bind a click handler to an individual isolated Sprite

```
 sprite.getChildren().forEach(
        s => s.setInteractive({ cursor: 'url(./src/games/gewgly/assets/images/pointer.png), pointer' })
    );
```

I used this method to tie isolated sprites, but it hasn't worked yet, is there a better way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Sprite in Phaser 3 cannot have children, so the `sprite.getChildren` part of your code worries me a bit. Only Groups have a `getChildren` method.

At its most simple:

```js
const player = this.add.sprite(x, y, texture);

player.setInteractive();

player.on('pointerdown', () => {

  console.log('You clicked the player sprite');

});

// Or, if you have a Group full of Sprites:

const sprites = yourGroup.getChildren();

sprites.forEach((child) => {

  child.setInteractive();

  child.on('pointerdown', () => {
    console.log('You clicked a Group sprite');
  });

});
```